# Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have the following AccountController class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/accounts")
public class AccountController {
private AccountService accountService;

@Autowired
public AccountController(AccountService accountService) {
    this.accountService = accountService;
}
... implemented methods here
}
```

The AccountService class is as below

```
public interface AccountService {
public Account findAccount(BigInteger id);

public Account createAccount(Account data);

public Account deleteAccount(String email);

public Boolean updateAccount(String email,String password);

public List<Account> findAllAccounts();

// public Account deleteAccount();

public Customer createCustomer(String accountId, Customer data);

public List<Customer> findCustomersByAccount(String accountId);

}
```

The AccountServiceImpl class is as below

```
@Service
```

public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService{

```
@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountRepo;

@Autowired
private CustomerRepository custRepo;
..implemented methods here
```

}

My servlet.xml has the following component scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sam.spring.web.rest.mvc" />
```

The /src/resource/context.xml has the following

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sam.spring.web.core.services"></context:component-scan>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sam.spring.web.core.repositories.jpa"></context:component-scan>
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController' defined in file ...

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.sam.spring.web.core.services.AccountService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

What have I done wrong in this setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `<context:component-scan base-package="com.sam.spring.web.rest.mvc, com.sam.spring.web.core.services, com.sam.spring.web.core.repositories.jpa" />`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `<context:annotation-config/>` in ur context ?

Comment: Yes I am. I have it placed after the <context:component ></context:component> tag in the context.xml